# Why when applying flex-direction column and justify-content center when trying to align a flex item at the start this doesn't work?

Tags: css, flexbox

I amm trying that the tomato color stripes in the columns are aligned at the top of each column, the left column is applied the property `justify-content: center;` and `flex-direction: column;` I have tried to align itself from the start using `justify-self: flex-start;` or `align-self: flex-start;` but neither achieves the effect I want.

Here the relevant section

Column

```
.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

The css for the element that I requires moving to the top

```
.mark {
  background-color: tomato;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  /* justify-self: flex-start; */
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Please take a look to the current state

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  
}

.one, .two {
  flex: 1
}

.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mark {
  background-color: tomato;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-self: flex-start;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table th, table td {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

table tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) > td, table tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) > th {
  background-color: #fff7db;
}

table tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, table tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th {
    background-color: #e5e6f3;
}

table th {
  height: 50px;
}

.collection {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="mark"></div>
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3" class="collection">Collection</th>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your advices

Comment: Do you want the `H1` and the `P` to be centered?

Comment: That's right, `h1` and `p` must be centered, but `mark` must stay on top

Comment: HTML:
`<div class="one">
            <div class="mark-wrap">
                <div class="mark"></div>
                <div class="text-holder">
                    <h1>Text</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

CSS:

  `.mark-wrap {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .text-holder {
        margin: auto;
    }`

hope that helped.

Comment: sorry kinda missed up since the mode closed the question I can't tide it up :(

Comment: no problem, I try and let you know

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: I just tried but with no success. my mistake is partially resolved, could you take a look at this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/ngjr7q4d/ content inside `text-holder` goes to the bottom

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/LRmx3vt/so.png 

that's how I see it, is that your desired result?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ahmaddalao/pen/PoNmNQv

Also please note when I run the code on my editor I had bootstrap. and the image I provided was the result I got.

Comment: i.ibb.co/LRmx3vt/so.png it's just what I'm looking for

Comment: How have you done so that the row of thead is the same size as the div with class mark?

Comment: I really didn't change anything you made I just add your code to my editor and I made some changes to the HTML and added two CSS classes and shared those with you. 
 Maybe it's bootstrap who's helping me there?. OK I removed bootstrap and I got the same result as I showed you in the image. nothing has changed.

Comment: Now its works, thank you. My mistake when following your example was not enclosing with mark-wrap all the content including text-holder

Comment: oh glad I was able to help :)